# Oracle SQL Language Reference Merge/Subquery Documentation Error?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, subquery, documentation

When using the [merge::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) `MERGE INTO ... USING subquery t_alias` it appears one must enclose the *subquery* in parenthesis like `MERGE INTO ... USING (subquery) t_alias`.  However, the Oracle SQL Language Reference documentation's syntax diagram  for [subquery::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2126435) appears to show that an optional path (via *query_block*) does not require parenthesis.  That is the documentation appears to allow both versions.

For example:

This following is invalid, but allowable per the documentation.

```sql
MERGE INTO tblA A
USING SELECT col FROM tblB B -- ORA-00903 invalid table name and "SELECT" is highlighted.
ON (A.id = B.id)
...
```

The following is valid (and also allowable per the documentation).

```sql
MERGE INTO tblA A
USING (SELECT col FROM tblB) B
ON (A.id = B.id)
...
```

According to [How to Read Syntax Diagrams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Graphic-Syntax-Diagrams.html#GUID-D22097D5-1E7A-4A17-862A-F0084732B3CE)

> If the syntax diagram has more than one path, then you can choose any path.

**Is there an Oracle SQL Language Reference documentation error?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you scroll right to the bottom of the (merge) documentation there are thumbs up/down buttons; clicking thumbs down will give you a feedback form where you can explain your concern/confusion. (You used to be able to report a documentation bug; no idea if these are treated the same.)

Answer (score 1):

In MERGE query, the operand used after USING clause is not exactly a sub query. It actually defines a table. For example: if you want to update a table from the values from another table.

```
MERGE INTO tblA A
USING tblB B
ON (A.id = B.id)
...
```

In case tblB has very huge amount of data and you want to optimise the 
perfomance, you can use a query to fetch required columns from the table.

```
MERGE INTO tblA A
USING (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tblB) B -- here we are not using complete table, 
instead we are using only required columns from the table
ON (A.id = B.id)
...
```

Merge is also similar to join, below is the better way of understanding

```
select * from tblA A
inner join tblB B
ON (A.id = B.id);
```

or

```
select * from tblA A
inner join (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tblB) B
ON (A.id = B.id);
```

The reason you get invalid table name is, when you do not enclose the select statement in brackets, Oracle will not know the aliases of the table you are using. So always enclose a bracket when you have a certain conditions in the query.

Comment: The question wasn't pertaining to semantics, but the syntax.  It's agreed that Oracle wouldn't be able to discern the t_alias of tblB from the t_alias of (SELECT ...FROM tblB) B.  This is the point, the syntax diagrams in the documentation ought to require parenthesis when using t_alias with a subquery.  As to the point about the operand after USING not exactly being a sub query, then Oracle ought to not call it a "subquery" in the diagram.